# Cómo actualizar una tabla asignándole a unos datos el valor de su dato "padre" de otra tabla

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando actualizar una tabla en Oracle SQL Developer y me está dando el siguiente problema:

> SQL command not properly ended

Tengo una relación 1:N en la cual quiero asignar el mismo valor que tiene un campo al resto de datos de la tabla que tenga el mismo código. La consulta que tengo ahora mismo es la siguiente:

```sql
    UPDATE MTRAS M 
       SET M.COD_ANCHOV = DT.COD_ANCHOV 
      FROM MTRAS M, D_TECN DT 
     WHERE DT.CODTR = M.TRAM AND
           M.HASTA IS NULL AND
           M.BOJO IS NULL AND
           M.TRAM = '010101'
```

Espero que puedan explicarme dónde puede encontrarse el fallo pues llevo mucho sin realizar un update de este tipo y no he conseguido entender nada de lo visto por internet.

Comment: Puedes probar a hacer un UPDATE SELECT

Answer (score 3):

Oracle no permite esa sintaxis para `UPDATE` con joins. Puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE MTRAS 
SET MTRAS.COD_ANCHOV = (SELECT D_TECN.COD_ANCHOV FROM D_TECN  
                        WHERE MTRAS.CODTR = D_TECN.TRAM)
WHERE  MTRAS.HASTA IS NULL AND
       MTRAS.BOJO IS NULL AND
       MTRAS.TRAM = '010101'
```

Comment: gracias @Lamak se ve que no es tampoco la solución, hice tal cual lo que dijiste y me dió el siguiente error: Error SQL: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row. Aún así gracias, aviso si doy con la solución

Comment: Te lo describo con algún tipo de ejemplo, D_TECN es un coche y tiene un dato que el codigo que identifica las medidas de sus puertas: COD_ANCHOV. MTRAS son las puertas de forma individual y vamos a poner el caso de que todas las medidas miden igual y posee tmb un codigo que identifica la medida. Pues bien, en la actualidad hay puertas que corresponden a un coche con sus valores a null o diferentes a lo establecido en la tabla del coche y quiero que todas las puertas tenga las medidas de su correspondiente coche. Espero que me hayas entendido @Lamak

Comment: @Javier: al final, ¿aceptaste la respuesta porque te funcionó o te siguió dando el error?

Comment: @JavierGT Es importante que aceptes una respuesta sólo cuando en verdad te soluciona el problema

Comment: Disculpa @Lamak la puse como solucionada porque pensaba que como respuesta tras unas pruebas con un único valor era válida aunque no queriendo el resultado que yo esperaba pues debo hacer un procedimiento, pero para solucionar el mismo problema que a mí le valdría a la gente, pero hoy estoy haciendo pruebas más específicas y no es correcta la solución. Pido disculpas.

Comment: @JavierGT No te preocupes, no es necesaria una disculpa. Simplemente tu comentario explicando que esto funciona para un valor está bien. La idea es que los usuarios que vean esta pregunta y respuesta entiendan bien lo que pasó y les pueda ser de ayuda